# How to change the index value of json array using spinner?

Tags: android, json, parsing

```
@Override
public void onResponse(String response){
    
    try {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response.toString());
        if (jArray.length() > 2) {
            JSONObject json_obj = jArray.getJSONObject(2);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to change the index value of the `getJSONObject(2)` using spinner.

Comment: "Change value of  `getJSONObject(2)`" You mean to change that `2` parameter?

Comment: yes
Can i change this using spinner or anything else
I want to show the covid cases in different states

Answer (score 0):

You can check this sample project:

MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);

        // set spinner values
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.json_options, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        // button click listener
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() - to get which item is chosen in spinner, indexed from 0
                Log.d("Info", "Selected JSON: " + (spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() + 1));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Do sth with value from spinner" />

</LinearLayout>
```

strings.xml

```
<string-array name="json_options">
    <item>JSON One</item>
    <item>JSON Two</item>
    <item>JSON Three</item>
</string-array>
```

So I think In your case it will look something like this:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(String response){
    
    try {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response.toString());
        if (jArray.length() > 2) {
            JSONObject json_obj = jArray.getJSONObject(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
        }
    }
}
```